# Spark: How to split an instance into Postivie/Negative Samples according to two columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, kaggle

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, 2, 3, '2','1','1'), (4, 5, 6, '3','2','1')]).toDF(['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3','Impressions','Clicks','ImpressionsMinusClicks'])
df.show()
```

[image]

And I would like to convert it into this (however don't know how to and if to apply `split()` and `explode()` to achieve this):

[image]

The key here is to basically copy every instance to match # of Impressions (e.g. 10 impressions instance turns into 10 rows), then of those rows mark them # Click times as a positive example, the remaining rows are marked # IMpressions - Click times as a negative example. Summing it up: An instance has 10 impressions, and 3 clicks. I want to transform it into 10 rows, 3 positive samples ("1" for clicked) and 7 negative samples ("0" for impressed/not clicked). The purpose is to use this for input into a classification models such as Naive Bayes or Logistic Regression. The origin of this is the Kaggle KDD Cup 2012 data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working, albeit "ugly" solution that works with PySpark, based on the answer and help provided by @TzachZohar. Please let me know or post an answer or comment if you have a more elegant way!

```
    # The first UDF we create is to map the number of impressions into a sequence
    impsIndexed = udf(lambda Impressions: range(0,Impressions), ArrayType(IntegerType()))

    # The second UDF is to map each impression into a 1 or 0 depending if that event had a matching click. So far this is equivalent to Tzach's solution, with the exception that I was not able to package both operations into a single UDF.
    IndicesToClicks = udf(lambda Impressed, Clicks: 1 if Impressed < Clicks else 0, IntegerType())

    # Next, I take the input data frame and apply the first UDF to it, creating a new data frame.
    df_new = df.withColumn('Impressed', explode(impsInd('Impressions')))
    df_new.show()

    # Lastly, I take this new data frame and apply the second UDF to it, achieving the final data frame.
    df_fin = df_new.withColumn('Clicked', toClicks('Impressed','Clicks')).select('ID1','ID2','ID3','Clicked')
    df_fin.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use `explode` on the result of a UDF that would produce a series of "events" - 1 for a click event and 0 for a non-clicked impression event:

```java
// We create a UDF which expects two columns (imps and clicks) as input, 
// and returns an array of "is clicked" (0 or 1) integers
val toClickedEvents = udf[Array[Int], Int, Int] {
  case (imps, clicks) => {
    // First, we map the number of imps (e.g. 3) into a sequence
    // of "imps" indices starting from zero; Each one would later
    // represent a single impression "event"
    val impsIndices = (0 until imps)

    // we map each impression "event", represented by its index, 
    // into a 1 or a 0: depending if that event had a matching click;
    // we do that by assigning "1" to indices lower than the number of clicks
    // and "0" for the rest
    val clickIndicatorPerImp = impsIndices.map(index => if (clicks > index) 1 else 0)

    // finally we just convert into an array, to comply with the UDF signature
    clickIndicatorPerImp.toArray
  }
}

// explode the result of the UDF and calculate ImpressedNotClicked
df.withColumn("Clicked", explode(toClickedEvents($"Impressions", $"Clicks")))
  .select($"ID1", $"ID2", $"ID3", $"Clicked", abs($"Clicked" - lit(1)) as "ImpressedNotClicked")
```

**NOTE**: original post was tagged with `scala`; If you can convert this into `python`, feel free to edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! I'm trying to translate the first line into python/PySpark. Would you be able to help?

Comment: if you could further elaborate on the components of the UDF, that would be helpful, I will then try to build it in Python... Do I understand correctly(?): you're defining a UDF that creates an Array of integers (two integers to be exact). The arguments for the UDF are (imps, clicks). Then I basically get lost...

Comment: Added some explanation inline, hope it helps; My python is too weak for me to help any further...